# swiftui ternary operator in view body

Tags: swift, swiftui, conditional-operator

inside a swiftyui body, based on news.urlToImage value, i need to be able to load either another view (LOadRemoteImageView, which is just another view which is accepting an optional url string to load remote image), either to display an Text string "no image url".

Following the syntax below, it works fine

```
if news.urlToImage == nil {
Text("no image url")
}else {
    LoadRemoteImageView(withURL: news.urlToImage!).frame(width: 140, height: 140)
}
```

however when trying to inline the code, it fails with no correct error message by intellisense

```
news.urlToImage == nil ? Text("no image") : LoadRemoteImageView(withURL: news.urlToImage!)
```

also tried to use map to display either of the two views if urlToImage: String is not nil, but fails as well

```
news.urlToImage.map {
$0 != nil ? LoadRemoteImageView(withURL: $0) : Text("no image")
```

}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is all about types ... result of line expression **must** generate single type. So if you so like ternary operator you should use it like

```
news.urlToImage == nil ? AnyView(Text("no image")) : 
     AnyView(LoadRemoteImageView(withURL: news.urlToImage!))
```

or something similar... as for me regular `if/else` is better.

Comment: extremely valuable, didn't know single line must return single type Thanks a bunch!