# How can I handle default values with images for an optional String property in a Swift struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working with an optional struct in Swift, where the default value is expected to be a string. However, I'd like to handle a scenario where the default value can also be an image. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Text(quotes.quote ?? Image(systemName: "circle.dashed") )
```

Can someone please guide me on how to convert this image fallback into a string when quotes.quote is nil?

My expectation was to set a default value for Text as a string, and if quotes.quote is nil, I wanted to use an image (in this case, "circle.dashed") as the fallback.

Comment: simply if quotes.quote != nil {
                    Text(quotes.quote!)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.dashed")
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to write it with a ternary operator, [a single expression must return single type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60027452/16157878), so you would have to write:

```
quotes.quote != nil ? AnyView(Text(quotes.quote!)) : AnyView(Image(systemName: "circle.dashed"))
```

However, this is a bit hard on the eye, and I'd like to avoid the force-unwrap:

```
if let quote = quotes.quote {
    Text(quote)
} else {
    Image(systemName: "circle.dashed")
}
```